# ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block SQL state: 25001 - Using PostgresSQL and pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Hi guys I'm stuck on a problem for my first database on Postgres and I cannot find a solution, I tried to see if it was a matter of setting autocommit on but apparently from postgres 9.x it's an inconclusive operation. The documentation suggests that it might be an error on permissions or a full disk.
This is the code

```
CREATE DATABASE datacamp_courses 
WITH 
OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;


CREATE TABLE datacamp_courses (
    course_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    course_instructor VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    topic VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL
    );
```

This is the error :

```
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
SQL state: 25001
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you running both those statements together (either both of them selected or neither selected)? If so then run them one at a time - select/highlight the first one, run it, then same for the second one.

Comment: Turn off auto commit before running that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is self explanatory: you cannot create a database in a transaction.

You can try to run your statements in `psql` (CLI) with runs in AUTOCOMMIT by default: it will work but note that the table will be created in current database (by default postgres) which is maybe not what you want. If you want to create a database and a table in this new database you can try:

```
  create database mydb;
  \connect mydb
  create table test(c int);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the db browser in Intellij idea, select the auto commit field from the database settings you are connecting to.